# Will serving many dependencies from a CDN slow the site down?

Tags: javascript, html, http, tcp, cdn

If I have an HTML page on my site with a large number of script tags pointing to http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com, will this slow down page loading? I'm thinking that it will fetch them all in a single TCP connection, but will make multiple GET requests, whereas if I provide them from my own server then all the javascript can be concatenated into a single file. Does this make a significant difference? Is it likely that the speed benefits of the CDN (caching, proximity, etc.) will at least mostly nullify it?

Update: I've just discovered jsDelivr which actually provides arbitrary concatenations of the libraries it hosts, e.g. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/react@0.13.3,jquery@2.1.4. However this means there's no way the user will have cached this combination from another site so they will potentially download more data.

Comment: missing an important concept helped improve page loading time .... *domain sharding*. However it is becoming obsolete in near future

Comment: What about a CDN that serves a single file? Instead of *you* serving the single big JS file just push it to he CDN. Note that the browser will only make a max of approx. 6 connections simultaneously to the same domain, so having it on a CDN is good, so you can serve the stuff that's not on the CDN

Comment: @user3211152 Until just now (see update) I thought that for free, public CDNs I would need a separate file for each separate library. I am not currently looking at paying for my own CDN hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple downloads require multiple HTTP connections.

Multiple HTTP connections do not require multiple TCP connections, as an existing TCP connection can be used subsequent requests (possibly even before the previous request has been dealt with, if pipelining is used).

As well as the fact that your particular situation has a choice between a mechanism that allows you to make a single request versus one that requires several are made, there are the following pros and cons:

Cons:

1. You need another DNS lookup.
2. You need at least one more TCP connection that cannot be the reuse of a previously opened connection.
3. You can end up with your server contactable by a given client while the CDN is not.

Pros:

1. It's less work for your sever to do.
2. Unless the connection is already being maxed out, it is likely that the client can download from two servers faster than it can from one.
3. If the resource is popular, there's a good chance of a given client having a cached copy before they even come to your site, and so either not needing to hit it at all, or just long enough to get a 304 (and the DNS-lookup is done).

This last *pro* only applies if you are using a shared published resource URI, not to using a CDN service for your own hosting. That case though allows for a greater use of that same CDN, so the pros will then apply to other resources.

The balance can not only go either way, but it can go one way for some clients and another for others.

Generally when it comes to questions of efficiency while we can, and must, reason about the matter to a certain extent, only testing can really tell us which is more efficient. This is also true here, but the testing must be done across different scenarios, with simulations of different client locations. If one doesn't end up always being the winner across those different scenarios you can be left guessing which are most important to you.

Answer (score 0):

It will not fetch them all in a single connection; a separate request will be made for each one. The impact on your site's performance will vary depending on how many the client has already cached, but in general fewer script requests will equal greater performance. As @user3211152 suggests, concat and minify your dependencies into a single file, and (optionally) serve it from the CDN for greater reliability / speed of access from across the globe.

Comment: Does the browser really open a new TCP connection for each request it needs to make, even if they're all to the same domain? Isn't that incredibly wasteful?

Comment: I missed the distinction between requests and connections, but requests consume resources and time too. Without a list of libs we can't do more than guess, but "a large number of files" will result in a large number of requests. If you include the spread of users' exposure to various library versions the likelihood that substantial numbers of users will have cached all or most of the libs falls. IMO you are most likely best served by concatenating the libs, but if you need to know for sure you should use Jon's advice and test different scenarios.